# Development wsgi server is getting stuck while returning a HttpResponse() in Django (debug=True)

Tags: django, django-views, wsgi, django-wsgi

I am sending username from the frontend using an ajax call to backends login() (in view.py) in django . where first I am verifing and then setting the session variables for the same. After this, I am returning a message whether login is successful or not using:

```
def login(request):

     user = request.POST.get('user')
     msg = verify_user_credentials(user)
     if msg == True:
         reuest.session['user'] = user
     return HttpResponse(msg)
```

But while returning it is getting stuck and holding a terminal. So, the whole tool is getting hung.

*login()* successfully checking the credentials and adding them up in session successfully each and every time but don't know why it is getting stuck while returning the HttpResponse(msg) in some cases.

**Additional Information:**

- *verify_user_credentials()* is an internal function that verifies the
  user credentials.
- I am using *debug = True*, As tool is running in development mode.

Comment: Does your code throw any errors or it's just stuck?

Comment: @crimsonpython24, my code is not throwing any error. It is just holding the terminal which causes the complete tool is getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using Nginx with the passenger as a server for the application issue resolved.